# Inconsistent behavior when typing a number into the search field

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, post-id

Over at the [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) community, when I type *1040* into the search box in the upper right corner and hit Enter, it immediately returns the [question with ID 1040](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1040/contractors-guideline-on-what-percentage-to-keep-when-hiring-a-sub-contractor), even though there are [plenty of posts containing *1040*](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=form%201040).  But when I type *193* into the search box, it returns a [list of search results](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=193) instead of the [question with ID 193](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/193/how-and-where-can-i-deposit-money-to-generate-future-payments-income).  Why the different behavior?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the search, retagging.

Comment: Reproduced on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=777777 ([proof there are posts with this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22777777%22))

Comment: "We only do this if the number is 4 or more digits" - from Jeff's answer to the linked question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10024/152859),if the search term is a number with at least four digits and this number is a valid ID of undeleted question, you will be redirected to that question regardless of search results.

So, this is by design and to actually look for such numbers, wrap them with quotes e.g. https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=%221040%22